# React native new Date() is not working as it is supposed to

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this code which shall format the given date:

```
  const postDate = new Date(date);
```

But whenever I try to use it like this:

```
        <Text style={styles.dateText}>{postDate}</Text>
```

I always get this error and I don't know how to fix it:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Fri Aug 28 2020 16:54:45 GMT+0400 (+04)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Any solutions on how to fix this issue please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't bind Objects inside JSX templates.

Convert your Date object to a string, and JSX will render it.

```
<Text style={styles.dateText}>{postDate.toDateString()}</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,I will be able to accept your answer in 9 minutes